# Element head is missing a required instance of child element title

Tags: html, laravel, laravel-4, w3c

I'm receiving this error: `Element head is missing a required instance of child element title.` on w3.org validator. It seems that my `<title></title>` tags are missing although I have title in my site, and also I can see title when I open website source using developer tools.

[This is link for w3.org](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fobjavi.net%2Fposts%2F3&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&ss=1&group=0&No200=1&user-agent=W3C_Validator%2F1.3+http%3A%2F%2Fvalidator.w3.org%2Fservices)

[and this is link from my site](http://objavi.net/posts/9)

Btw, I'm using Laravel 4 Blade templating engine. Can someone tell what's wrong here?

Comment: Just a heads up, if it's someone's first time visiting that site, they will get an error because $_COOKIE['visited'] is not set.  That may also be why it's saying you are missing a title because the cookie is probably not being set for that webcrawler

Comment: @user3158900 I'm using that cookie just to track number of visits, it doesn't stop you from accessing any content.

Comment: You are attempting to use it in a query which is throwing an exception.  Once the cookie is set though, I can see your content.  If you delete your cookies and reload the page, you can see this.

Comment: Thank you man, it's fixed now. Although w3.org reports some other errors, but nevermind, I fixed the problem I had. Thank you again

Answer (score 0):

The solution was in the comments apparently, posting it here to remove this question from the Unanswered list:

> If it's someone's first time visiting that site, they will get an error because $_COOKIE['visited'] is not set. That may also be why it's saying you are missing a title because the cookie is probably not being set for that webcrawler